# Working of __asm__ __volatile__ ("" : : : "memory")

Tags: c, gcc, arm, embedded-linux, volatile

What basically `__asm__ __volatile__ ()` does and what is significance of `"memory"` for ARM architecture?

Comment: `asm _volatile_` explained in (http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.4). But shouldn't this be two separated questions?

Comment: @phoeagon: this line, as is, is a unified operation of a compiler memory access scheduling barrier - while the two questions might be relevant enough separately, that would be unlikely to answer the question asked.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```
asm volatile("" ::: "memory");
```

creates a compiler level memory barrier forcing optimizer to not re-order memory accesses across the barrier.

For example, if you need to access some address in a specific order (probably because that memory area is actually backed by a different device rather than a memory) you need to be able tell this to the compiler otherwise it may just optimize your steps for the sake of efficiency.

Assume in this scenario you must increment a value in address, read something and increment another value in an adjacent address.

```
int c(int *d, int *e) {
        int r;
        d[0] += 1;
        r = e[0];
        d[1] += 1;
        return r;
}
```

Problem is compiler (`gcc` in this case) can rearrange your memory access to get better performance if you ask for it (`-O`). Probably leading to a sequence of instructions like below:

```
00000000 <c>:
   0:   4603        mov r3, r0
   2:   c805        ldmia   r0, {r0, r2}
   4:   3001        adds    r0, #1
   6:   3201        adds    r2, #1
   8:   6018        str r0, [r3, #0]
   a:   6808        ldr r0, [r1, #0]
   c:   605a        str r2, [r3, #4]
   e:   4770        bx  lr
```

Above values for `d[0]` and `d[1]` are loaded at the same time. Lets assume this is something you want to avoid then you need to tell compiler not to reorder memory accesses and that is to use `asm volatile("" ::: "memory")`.

```
int c(int *d, int *e) {
        int r;
        d[0] += 1;
        r = e[0];
        asm volatile("" ::: "memory");
        d[1] += 1;
        return r;
}
```

So you'll get your instruction sequence as you want it to be:

```
00000000 <c>:
   0:   6802        ldr r2, [r0, #0]
   2:   4603        mov r3, r0
   4:   3201        adds    r2, #1
   6:   6002        str r2, [r0, #0]
   8:   6808        ldr r0, [r1, #0]
   a:   685a        ldr r2, [r3, #4]
   c:   3201        adds    r2, #1
   e:   605a        str r2, [r3, #4]
  10:   4770        bx  lr
  12:   bf00        nop
```

It should be noted that this is only compile time memory barrier to avoid compiler to reorder memory accesses, as it puts no extra hardware level instructions to flush memories or wait for load or stores to be completed. CPUs can still reorder memory accesses if they have the architectural capabilities and memory addresses are on `normal` type instead of `strongly ordered` or `device` ([ref](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0211k/Babcddgd.html)).

Comment: In this particular case the same effect can be achieved in standard C by declaring the parameters like this: `int c(volatile int *d, volatile int *e)`

Answer (score 31):

This sequence is a compiler memory access scheduling barrier, as noted in the article referenced by Udo. This one is GCC specific - other compilers have other ways of describing them, some of them with more explicit (and less esoteric) statements.

`__asm__` is a gcc extension of permitting assembly language statements to be entered nested within your C code - used here for its property of being able to specify side effects that prevent the compiler from performing certain types of optimisations (which in this case might end up generating incorrect code).

`__volatile__` is required to ensure that the **asm** statement itself is not reordered with any other volatile accesses any (a guarantee in the C language).

`memory` is an instruction to GCC that (sort of) says that the inline asm sequence has side effects on global memory, and hence not just effects on local variables need to be taken into account.

Comment: +1 This answer plus **Udo** is correct.  This is a memory barrier for a *compiler* only.  It will not work for SMP hardware.

Comment: So how to you decide, where to insert the asm volatile statement ?

Comment: @Soundararajan: That question does not have a short answer. I would recommend reading Paul McKenney's excellent paper on memory access ordering requirements: http://www.rdrop.com/~paulmck/scalability/paper/whymb.2009.04.05a.pdf and the Linux kernel overview of memory barriers: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt

Answer (score 11):

The meaning is explained here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering

Basically it implies that the assembly code will be executed where you expect it. It tells the compiler to not reorder instructions around it. That is what is coded before this piece of code will be executed before and what is coded after will be executed after.

Answer (score -6):

```
static inline unsigned long arch_local_irq_save(void)
{
    unsigned long flags;

    asm volatile(
        "   mrs %0, cpsr    @ arch_local_irq_save\n"
        "   cpsid   i"      //disabled irq
        : "=r" (flags) : : "memory", "cc");
return flags;
}
```

Comment: Please only post answers here if you're actually answering the question at the top of the page. The question here asks for explanations, you did not provide anything like that.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.