# what's the best pactise to write many comparison operations in C++?

Tags: c++

I use the following codes to illustrate my question:

```
if( a== 0)
{
   if(b==0)
    {
         if(c == 0)
         {
            //
          }
     }

}
```

vs

```
if((a==0)&&(b==0)&&(c==0))
{

}
```

The first code fragment is the same with the second on when it comes from functionalities. The second one is more concise and easy to understand. I just wondering after code compilation whether both code fragments perform the same. Will the second runs faster? Here, we assume there are many comparions. For example

```
if((a==0)&&....(y==0)&&(z==0))
{

}
```

Comment: why not look at the compiler emitted code, or run a test to see which is faster

Comment: It most likely won't matter one iota for any real application compiled with an optimizing compiler. If things such as these (trivialities) are what you are worried about, then I suspect you are either playing with toy example programs or you have *much* bigger problems.

Comment: Just a note on style: you don't need the extra parentheses in `if (a==0&&b==0&c==0)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just wondering after code compilation whether both code fragments perform the same.

**There most likely won't be any significant performance difference** - chained [builtin logical operators are **short-circuited**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical), which means that...

```
if(a && b) { }
```

...is *semantically equivalent* to...

```
if(a) { if (b) { } }
```

Regardless, [the discussion in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061281/can-the-c-compiler-optimizer-violate-short-circuiting-and-reorder-memory-accesse) *("Can the C compiler optimizer violate short-circuiting and reorder memory accesses for operands in a logical-AND expression?")* points out that compilers have some optimization freedom even with short-circuited logical expressions.

Therefore, the only *true way* of making sure that the performance is unchanged **is measuring and looking at the generated assembly**.

---

Regarding *"style"*, I think this is a purely subjective issue.