# Is the order in which operands are evaluated for logical operators guaranteed in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have this Python code:

```
if a() or b():
   do_something()
```

Will a() always execute before b()?

I know from similar code in C, C compilers will sometimes optimize b() to execute before a(). Is this also the case with the Python interpreter?

I'm using Python 3.10 if that affects it

Comment: What "similar" C code?

Comment: Such an optimization would not be legal in C for *logical* boolean operators (`&&`, `||`) because they are short-circuiting.  Perhaps you are confusing them with *bitwise* operators (`&`, `|`).

Comment: I had some c code a while back that looked something like: ```while(a() || b()) { do_something(); }``` and it got optimized into b() || a(). It was extremely frustrating to figure that out. I def had some optimization flags going which may have affected it. @jamesdlin

Comment: @Brett If that happened then your C compiler was broken and non-conformant.

Comment: @jamesdlin Aren't compilers allowed to do such things if it makes no observable difference?

Comment: @Brett Not in this case. `&&` and `||` are *required* to create a sequence point that guarantees that the left operand is evaluated first.  There are many other types of expressions where evaluation order is unspecified and thus implementation-dependent.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/628526/

Comment: @jamesdlin So is for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38061717/12671057) wrong, or do I misunderstand it?

Comment: @KellyBundy Well, the point is that the compiler must generate code that at a macroscopic level behaves as-if the left operand is evaluated first.  At a microscopic level, ok, the compiler can reorder *if* there are no observable differences, but if there are no observable differences, you can't tell which was evaluated first anyway.

Comment: @jamesdlin Yes, I'm wondering how Brett was able to tell, and why that was a problem.

Comment: @jamesdlin I was using Microchip's MPLAB XC8 compiler for the code. I was getting some unexplainable results in my code that were obviously wrong. I tried everything I could think of but was still stumped. Then I tried splitting the while loop from ```while(a() || b()) { do_something(); }``` to ```while(1) { if (a()) {do_something();} else if (b()) {do_something();} else {break;}}``` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

#### `a()` will execute before `b()`

This is guaranteed.

In fact, b() will not execute if a() is already true-like.

#### A commenter was asking where the guarantee is

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not

[image]

For the short-circuiting to work, i.e. only call the second if the first is false-like, the first must be executed before the decision is made on whether to call the second. Therefore the first *will* be called before the second.

Comment: @KellyBundy [*Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that while evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the left-hand side.*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order)

Answer (score 0):

[Section 6.16](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order) of the language refers states that expressions are evaluated left to right, so yes `a()` will always execute before `b()`, **doesn't matter which operand is between them**:

> Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that while
> evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the
> left-hand side.
>
> In the following lines, expressions will be evaluated in the
> arithmetic order of their suffixes:
>
> ```
> expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4
> (expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4)
> {expr1: expr2, expr3: expr4}
> expr1 + expr2 * (expr3 - expr4)
> expr1(expr2, expr3, *expr4, **expr5)
> expr3, expr4 = expr1, expr2
> ```

Whether or not `b()` is executed at all depends on the operand type.

For boolean operands, as described by @Eureka in their answer, the answer is that `b()` is evaluated only if necessary to compute the result (i.e. the operand will "short circuit"). For other operands `b()` will be evaluated unless `a()` raises an exception.

Comment: `print(1) if not print(2) else print(3)` prints `2` before it prints `1`.

Comment: @KellyBundy So what? That's a **conditional** expression. Obviously you must evaluate the condition before the "body". If it printed `1` before `2` then it would not make sense as an expression. It's like saying that in `a + b` you expect the `+` to be evaluted before its operands